# Button element not responding

Tags: javascript, html

Simple question, for some reason this piece of code doesn't work, it's not complicated, but whenever I try to run it in browser it doesn't respond. Is there something I'm missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #F3F781;}

#container {height: 100px; padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0;}

#box1 {width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; border-radius: 10px; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; background-color: #F5DA81; display: inline-block;}

#box2 {width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; border-radius: 10px; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; background-color: #58FA58; display: inline-block;}

#box3 {width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; border-radius: 10px; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; background-color: #58FAD0; display: inline-block;}

#box4 {width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; border-radius: 10px; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; background-color: #F5A9F2; display: inline-block;}

</style>

<script>

function write(){
     console.log("hello");
}   

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="box1"><p id="info">text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box2"><p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box3"><p>text</p>
        </div>
    <div id="box4"><p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<div>
<button onclick="write()">write</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I may be being a bit dence, but for some reason the button script just wont work. I can't see anything wrong with it at all. Is there something I'm missing.

Thanks for any help, and I'm aware of my low quality questions. I just really am quite stuck on this.

Answer (score 4):

Change your function name to something other than "write()" because that's already an existing javascript method.

Comment: great thanks, I did think it was something like that, even tested. Must have got a bit lost for a moment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `write()` as a function name because that might call `document.write()` - which is what currently happens - when you click the buton, everything disappears, because you're `document.write()`ing nothing!

Change it to something else, like `test()`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F3F781;
}
#container {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  background-color: #F5DA81;
  display: inline-block;
}
#box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  background-color: #58FA58;
  display: inline-block;
}
#box3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  background-color: #58FAD0;
  display: inline-block;
}
#box4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  background-color: #F5A9F2;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function test() {
    //console.log("hello");
    alert('hello');
  }
</script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="box1">
    <p id="info">text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box4">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <button onclick="test()">write</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ᔕᖺᘎᕊ is right.

But you should also consider removing the onclick attribute, just for best practices' sake. Code used this way goes in the global scope, and also runs through `eval()` which could be a security concern.

Consider scoping it to an input or button's id:

**JS**:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    console.log('working');
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div>
    <input id="btn" value="write" type="submit"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/milesrobinson/e9myj0kw/